# Apache Derby - Database created but not found

Tags: java, web-applications, derby

This is in continuation to my previous [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRSrE.png)

I'm trying to embed a derby database in my web application. I'm able to embed it, though I am facing glitches. Here's the snapshot of my project structure.

[image: Project structure]

I wonder why `class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbededDriver")` is throwing exception?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbededDriver
```

To overcome this, I have used

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
```

Which works well. Why is it so? Also, Where would it create database if coded like this. I cannot spot the database.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true");
```

I checked in tomcat webapps and eclipse workspace, I didn't find database.

If given this way, I can spot it.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:E:/MyDbTest;create=true");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbededDriver")
```

Threw an exception because there is a 'd' missing from embedded.

See here for information about specifying the location of databases on the file system.

[connecting to a file-based derby database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666313/connecting-to-a-file-based-derby-database/10666543#10666543)

Comment: I see that the database is created in the eclipse installation directory.

Comment: When deployed through tomcat, it's creating database inside bin directory of tomcat

Comment: Default would be current working directory, most operating systems that is where the program (eclipse.exe or java for tomcat) is launched from.