# db.lck appears while compiling a java program using a derby database

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, netbeans-8, javadb

Recently I have been trying a lot and scratching everywhere to connect to a derby database using NetBeans 8.0. After a lot of research in SO (**[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184625/apache-derby-database-created-but-not-found)**, **[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653905/database-not-found-error-in-apache-derby)**, **[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184866/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-table-view-x-does-not-exist)**, **[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996818/is-it-necessary-to-create-tables-each-time-you-connect-the-derby-database/23051822#23051822)**) and everywhere else I am unable to understand that how to make it go away.I realize this is the reason :-**(the `db.lck`)** that I am not getting a connection to the embedded apache derby DB.

I notice that `db.lck` appears while I compile the Java program. **Is that a reason that I am denied to a embedded apache derby connection?**

**N.B :-**
1. I connected to the JavaDB Server.
2. Disconnected the connection to the DB while compiling the program.
3. Added the relevant jar file `derby.jar`.
4. Created the database with default schema `APP` used username and password both as `app`.
5. Removed the `create=true` option from the connection string.
6. I can view and manipulate the data through the SQL console in NetBeans 8.0

Providing the code below for further reference :

**test.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class test
{
public static void main(String args [])
{
    try { 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Dhruvh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ApacheDerby/derbytest","app","app");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from \"APP\".TABLE1");
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
               System.out.println("Id : "+rs.getInt(1) +" "+" name :"+rs.getString(2));
            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println("No word matching in database");
            }
        } catch (SQLException err) {
           System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using:-

`PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from APP.TABLE1");`
`PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from TABLE1");`
`PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from app.table1"); //table was created in lower case`

But everything I mention above gave the same error:-
**`Table/View 'APP.TABLE1' does not exist.`**

StackTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'APP.TABLE1' does not exist.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:12)
```

`Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'APP.TABLE1' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)`

Also proving a snapshot of the created DB
[image]

Please tell if any further references are needed to solve the problem.

**Thanks for you patience**

Comment: **Is there anybody who has faced a similar situation?**

Answer (score 0):

You gave derby location of a database that doesn't exist, so it tries to create the database itself.

```
jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Dhruvh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ApacheDerby/src/derbytest;**create=true**
```

The bold part is a default argument which you leave out in your driver creation.

You can connect to the database but there doesn't exist a table you want to access. You have to fix the location of the database. Also if you are connected to the db through your program(looks like mplab x ?), you need to terminate that connection first.

Comment: no I mistakenly posted wit that location. The original location is
`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/Dhruvh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ApacheDerby/derbytest;create=true","app","app");`
**Corrected in the question**, and I cross checked it now once agin the database folder is still there

Comment: Still the error exists and I am not using any aplication like mplab x

Comment: you are still connecting to two different databases. run this before accessing the table.

CREATE TABLE APP.TABLE1 (ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE APP.TABLE1 ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR (30);

Comment: `CREATE TABLE APP.TABLE1 (ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);` gave
`Error code 30000, SQL state X0Y32: Table/View 'TABLE1' already exists in Schema 'APP'.`

Comment: ` ALTER TABLE APP.TABLE1 ADD COLUMN NAME VARCHAR (30);` gave `Error code 30000, SQL state X0Y32: Column 'NAME' already exists in Table/View '"APP"."TABLE1"'.`

Comment: and now what do u get when you try 
select * from APP.TABLE1

Comment: Thats what I am saying that the schema and table is there, but somewhere something is missing. I also mentioned the `db.lck` factor which appears while compiling the program

Comment: I wish I could attach the screenshot here but `select * from APP.TABLE1` showed all the rows with data as I mentioned on the screenshot above

Comment: i need you to run these statements in your java code where you get the error. as in  stm =con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE APP.TABLE1 (ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79978/discussion-between-mustangdc-and-marcin-deszczynski).